# Search users using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How do I search users using the Facebook Graph API?

I've tried:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/search?q={name}&type=user&access_token={token}&appsecret_proof={proof}

GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/search?q={name}&type=user&access_token={token}&appsecret_proof={proof}
```

But both return empty data:

```
{"data":[]}
```

I saw a question which mentioned that some search features had been deprecated in API v2.0. Is it still possible to do a user search? I can't find any Facebook API reference for doing a user search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was because I was using a test user account. I tested with a real account and it's working.

> GET graph.facebook.com/v2.12/search?q={name}&type=user

- Requires access_token.
- Requires appsecret_proof if "Require App Secret" is enabled.
- Returns empty data with test user account.